# Powershell: Select Range with column Number

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a Script which took the Column number($lc) and Row -Number ($sr / $lr).

Now I#d like to selcet a Range from ($lc - 7)($sr) to ($lc)($lr).

Problem I don't how to Convert Column Number into letter? **OR** How can I adress a Range by using the Number?

```
$file = "C:\Test\Excel_Matrix.xlsx"
#Program definieren
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
#im hintergrund ausführen
$excel.visible = $false


    $table = $null
    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($file)
    $table = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("Matrix")

    ###########
    #Basisdaten
    ###########
    
   

        $table = $null
        $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($file)
        $table = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("Matrix")
        
        IF($table -ne $null)
        {
            #Last Row lr
            $LetzteZeile = $table.Range("A10:A1000").Find("S999").row
            # start row sr
            $StartZeile = $table.Range("A10:A1000").Find("S002").row
            # last column lc
            $LetzteSpalte = $table.UsedRange.Find($LastText).Column
            
            $StartZeile
            $LetzteZeile
            

            **### DON'T WORK ###**   
            
            $table.Range(.Cells($StartZeile,1),.Cells($LetzteZeile,$LetzteSpalte)
   
        }

        $workbook.Close()
        $excel.Quit()
        $excel = $null
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you considered using the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel). That could make your life way easier. 

Comment: Try to use [R1C1 style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/numeric-columns-and-rows)

Comment: Wath ist the corrcet Syntax for R1C1? I tired `$table.Range($table.Cells($Step.Row, 6),$table.Cells($Step.Row, ($LetzteSpalte-9)))`  AND `$table.Range($table.Cells.Item($Step.Row, 6).FormulaR1C1,$table.Cells.Item($Step.Row, ($LetzteSpalte-9)).FormulaR1C1)` But it Don't works...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thats wath realy work:

```
$exBefRange = ($table.Cells.Item($StartZeile.Row, 6).address($false,$false) + ":" + $table.Cells.Item($LetzteSpalte.Row, ($LetzteSpalte-9)).address($false,$false))
```

But maybe, many ways go to Rome.

Comment: This uses different variables (`$Step`) and arguments (`6`, `-9`) than what is in your question and seemingly attempts to return an _address_ of the range in question, which is not what your question asks for.

Answer (score 1):

The (implied parameterized `.Item()` property of) the [`.Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells) property *does* accept numeric values to identify a cell, namely `1`-based row and column numbers.

It looks like the only problem with your code was that you didn't specify a range/worksheet object on which to call `.Cells()`:

Therefore:

```
$table.Range(
  $table.Cells($StartZeile, 1),
  $table.Cells($LetzteZeile, $LetzteSpalte)
)
```

---

You probably thought that `$table` could be omitted before the `.Cells()` calls because *VBA* allows you to do so via `With` statements, such as in the following example, where the object to operate on in property access / method calls inside the block is *implied* by the `With` operand:

```vb
' !! Works in VBA only.
With Worksheets(1) 
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), _ 
           .Cells(10, 10))
End With
```

However, PowerShell has *no* equivalent construct.

Comment: Unliky IT don't work :S I Tried: `$table.Range($table.Cells($Step.Row, 6),$table.Cells($Step.Row, ($LetzteSpalte-9)))` AND `$table.Range($table.Cells.Item($Step.Row, 6).FormulaR1C1,$table.Cells.Item($Step.Row, ($LetzteSpalte-9)).FormulaR1C1)`

Comment: @TheRob87, I don't know what your comment is trying to say, especially since it uses different variables (`$Step`) and arguments (`-9`, `-6`) than in the question, but, as far I can tell, the solution in this answer works, and addresses the question you asked.